# post image URL automatically to a custom field

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress.. I'm looking for a way to add the first uploaded image in a post automatically to a custom field named "Image".

Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self

Here is the final code that adds the thumbnail url to a custom field named Image.

```
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
        return $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    } else {
        return '';  // or a default thumbnail url
    }
}


add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 'w_thumbnail_src');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_id) {
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image', w_thumbnail_src(), true);
}
}
```